# How to remove ‘password cannot be empty’ msg on the registration form

Tags: magento

In my app(Magento v1.7), I don’t want user to input their password when registration. So I comment out the following code on page app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml

```
<ul class="form-list">
     <li class="fields">
         <div class="field">
              <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
              <div class="input-box">
                   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
               <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
               <div class="input-box">
                     <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
               </div>
           </div>
      </li>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
</ul>
```

But the warning message ‘The password cannot be empty.’ is still displayed when registration. How to remove this warning msg?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is validated at Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::validate() so you either override this function or make a hidden field `name="password"` and input some dummy info there you can later override with your generated passwords whatsoever. However this might be a security hole if you don't overwrite the password right away.

Comment: I have made password field hidden and give the dummy value (i.e. 123456). What i want is to give the auto-generated password to user once their have been approved. If the password has set to 123456 in hidden field. When user login, they need to input the 123456 or auto-generated password?

Comment: In this case you need to write an extension that will observe the `customer_register_success` event and update users passwords.

Comment: Sure. Just need to figure out how much. Are you familiar with creating Magento extensions?

Comment: I just started Magento 3 weeks ago. It will be really grateful if you can provide the whole extension. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Remove the class "required-entry" from the password field.

Comment: I had deleted the above code from register.phtml. But the msg is sitll displayed.

Comment: thats just the css class.  are you just guessing?

Comment: With that class only the JS validate the field.

Comment: @Sankar Raj, Version v1.7.0.2